# Enviar variável de página html para outra página usando javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, apache-cordova

A minha página recebe informações do meu js, esta assim o meu código:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    tblText += '<a href="teste.html"><table id="t01" class="table-bordered">';
    tblText += '<tr><th>Protocolo</th><td>' + results.rows.item(i).protocolo + '</td></tr>';
    tblText += '<tr><th>Status</th><td>' + results.rows.item(i).status + '</td></tr>';
    tblText += '</table></a>'
    var meuDepartamento = results.rows.item(i).nomeDepartamento;
    document.getElementById("tabelaSolicitacao").innerHTML = tblText;           
}
```

Gostaria que quando clicasse nesta tabela (que é exibida no meu html), ele enviasse o `results.rows.item(i).protocolo` para a nova janela `teste.html`, eu não sei como fazer isto usando JavaScript.

Comment: Você utiliza `JQuery` no seu projeto? Ou somente `AngularJS` ?

Comment: Sim faço uma query no meu BD, antes de iniciar este for

Comment: Não `Query` e sim `JQuery` http://jquery.com/

Comment: Conseguiu entender o que eu disse?

Comment: Entendi, eu utilizo sim

Comment: Blz, vou tem passar um script para criação de sessão via `jQuery` pera ai.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução é utilizar o [armazenamento local (localStorage)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) como descrito [aqui.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646947/phonegap-pass-js-data-between-the-pages)

Por exemplo:

```
//Escrever um valor
localStorage.fruta = 'banana';

//Exibir o valor armazenado
console.log(localStorage.fruta);
```

Answer (score 0):

Vou passar uma coisa que vai mudar sua vida com `JavaScript` e um ***Script*** em `jQuery` para criação de `Session` com isso você poderá passar suas variáveis e muito mais via `JavaScript` pelo site.

***Script para Criação de Sessões:***

```
(function($) {

    $.session = {

        _id: null,

        _cookieCache: undefined,

        _init: function() {
            if (!window.name) {
                window.name = Math.random();
            }
            this._id = window.name;
            this._initCache();

            // See if we've changed protcols

            var matches = (new RegExp(this._generatePrefix() + "=([^;]+);")).exec(document.cookie);
            if (matches && document.location.protocol !== matches[1]) {
                this._clearSession();
                for (var key in this._cookieCache) {
                    try {
                        window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, this._cookieCache[key]);
                    } catch (e) {};
                }
            }

            document.cookie = this._generatePrefix() + "=" + document.location.protocol + ';path=/;expires=' + (new Date((new Date).getTime() + 120000)).toUTCString();

        },

        _generatePrefix: function() {
            return '__session:' + this._id + ':';
        },

        _initCache: function() {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            this._cookieCache = {};
            for (var i in cookies) {
                var kv = cookies[i].split('=');
                if ((new RegExp(this._generatePrefix() + '.+')).test(kv[0]) && kv[1]) {
                    this._cookieCache[kv[0].split(':', 3)[2]] = kv[1];
                }
            }
        },

        _setFallback: function(key, value, onceOnly) {
            var cookie = this._generatePrefix() + key + "=" + value + "; path=/";
            if (onceOnly) {
                cookie += "; expires=" + (new Date(Date.now() + 120000)).toUTCString();
            }
            document.cookie = cookie;
            this._cookieCache[key] = value;
            return this;
        },

        _getFallback: function(key) {
            if (!this._cookieCache) {
                this._initCache();
            }
            return this._cookieCache[key];
        },

        _clearFallback: function() {
            for (var i in this._cookieCache) {
                document.cookie = this._generatePrefix() + i + '=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
            }
            this._cookieCache = {};
        },

        _deleteFallback: function(key) {
            document.cookie = this._generatePrefix() + key + '=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
            delete this._cookieCache[key];
        },

        get: function(key) {
            return window.sessionStorage.getItem(key) || this._getFallback(key);
        },

        set: function(key, value, onceOnly) {
            try {
                window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
            } catch (e) {}
            this._setFallback(key, value, onceOnly || false);
            return this;
        },

        'delete': function(key) {
            return this.remove(key);
        },

        remove: function(key) {
            try {
                window.sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
            } catch (e) {};
            this._deleteFallback(key);
            return this;
        },

        _clearSession: function() {
            try {
                window.sessionStorage.clear();
            } catch (e) {
                for (var i in window.sessionStorage) {
                    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(i);
                }
            }
        },

        clear: function() {
            this._clearSession();
            this._clearFallback();
            return this;
        }

    };

    $.session._init();

})(jQuery);
```

***Como utilizar:***

```
// DEFINIR SESSÃO
$.session.set('nome_da_session', 'valor_da_session');

// RECUPERAR SESSÃO
$.session.get('nome_da_session');
// OUTPUT "valor_da_session"

// LIMPAR TODAS AS SESSÕES
$.session.clear();

// CRIAR E RECUPERAR SESSÃO AO MESMO TEMPO
$.session.set('nome_da_session', 'valor_da_session').get('nome_da_session');
// OUTPUT > "valor_da_session"

// REMOVER SESSÃO ESPECÍFICA
$.session.remove('nome_da_session');
```

Espero que ajude.